# How to filter queryset to current user in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-tables2

I have a site that grabs all the records that is listed under the current user.

Right now it grabs and filters it to all the available records and then filters it to the current user. Is there a way to make it so it doesn't have to do the initial filtering?

```
class PromiseView(SingleTableView):
    queryset = Promise.objects.filter(deleted__isnull=True)
    table_class = PromiseTable
    template_name = 'promise.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        

        return self.queryset.filter(
            windows_user=self.request.user, # There has to be a better way for this one.
        )
```

I would want to make it so the initial query set is equal to

```
queryset = Promise.objects.filter(windows_user=self.request.user,deleted__isnull=True)
```

and get rid of the get_queryset function.
It makes no sense to query the entire database first and then query it again to filter it to how I want it.

Here is the model

```
class Promise(models.Model):
    windows_user = models.CharField('Windows', max_length=20)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField('Date')
    notes = models.CharField('note', max_length=100)
    deleted = models.DateTimeField('Deleted', null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'form_promise'
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['windows_user','deleted', ], name='index01'),
        ]
```

Comment: Can you share the model?

Comment: Exactly why do you need the `[10:len(...)]` part?

Comment: I have shared the model. I have removed the length part as that is irrelevant to the problem. I want to be able to access the current users username without having to use the get_queryset function

Comment: where is the Promise model related to the User model? Based on your posted code, you haven't actually connected them, unless you did it on a custom User model. 'windows_user' is just a CharField...you're probably wanting to define 'user' as a field on Promise, with ForeignKey or M2M relation to User.

Comment: Im currently having them authenticate themselves by their windows username. The site detects their windows username.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *need* to include the first `queryset = ...`, you can just use the `get_queryset()` to populate the data. If you'd like to be explicit then you could initialize an empty queryset with `qs.none()` which won't hit the db, and then return the actual data from `get_queryset()`.

```
class PromiseView(SingleTableView):
    queryset = Promise.objects.none()  # optional
    table_class = PromiseTable
    template_name = 'promise.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Promise.objects.filter(
            deleted__isnull=True,
            windows_user=self.request.user.username,  # I think you need user.username here.
        )
```